Flexbox justify content, but not include first item
Simply put, is there a way to justify the content of a flexbox but exclude the first item from this? The easiest way is to take the item out of the flexbox, but I'm just wondering if it's possible to skip over the first item before the justify-content takes effect.
<div class="flex">
    <div class="exclude">exclude</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
</div>

Theoretically it should look like:
(1)     (2)     (3)     (4)     (5)
exclude item    item    item    item

Where the space between (1) and (2) is native and not being done by the flex (assume it's 1px between the two words) but the rest of the items are spaced due to justify-content: between; for example.

You can try using a wrapper too:


.flex-container {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="flex-wrapper">
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
  </div>
</div>




Play with margin:


.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.flex .item {
  margin-inline: auto;
}
.flex :nth-child(1 of .item) {
  margin-left: 5px; /* the tiny margin after the excluded item */
}
.flex :nth-last-child(1 of .item) {
  margin-right: 0; /* last item with 0 margin right */
}
<div class="flex">
    <div class="exclude">exclude</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
</div>




This does not add anything to my answer actually.

@NijatMursali you answer is actually wrong ...

OP mentioned that Where the space between (1) and (2) is native and not being done by the flex (assume it's 1px between the two words) but the rest of the items are spaced due to justify-content: between; for example..

Use the property justify-self on .exclude

Justify self is ignored on flex items.
